# Free or Open Personal Digital Cerificate of Signing Documents?

Tags: digital-certificate, pkcs#12

I need to sign a pdf file with my own e-signature using a certificate where can i get one pfx file.

Comment: You need to rephrase your question.  Right now, it's incredibly vague.  Do you need a SSL cert? Or some other kind of digital key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As thedz commented, your question is rather vague. Thawte offers free personal certificates [here](http://www.thawte.com/secure-email/personal-email-certificates/). Is that what you need?

I see you updated your question. You can generate your own pfx file using OpenSSL as follows:

```
# create a file containing key and self-signed certificate
openssl req \
  -x509 -nodes -days 365 \
  -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout mycert.pem -out mycert.pem

# export mycert.pem as PKCS#12 file, mycert.pfx
openssl pkcs12 -export \
  -out mycert.pfx -in mycert.pem \
  -name "My Certificate"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java or C# you can use iText.
See [link](http://itextpdf.sourceforge.net/howtosign.htm) for details. You can also get some leads on how to get your license, according to the license you need.
There's also a very useful book (iText in action) you can refer to.